# Date Difference

Tags: php, datetime

I'm looking for a function like date_diff that I can use for 5.2.12? I can't find one. Is there one I didn't see that will work. The point of this is because I'm trying to see if there has been 10 minutes expired between two datetime variables.

Comment: u have in http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php some comments of how o use in php < 5.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if date_diff itself does not work, it is most likely due to the date objects not being setup properly. However if you want a custom function that does the same, you can take a look at...

[How to calculate the difference between two dates using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php)

Comment: But I have times in mine though not just a year-month-day.

Comment: Scroll down, about 3 answers, it showed a version that include time (even in seconds)

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
if ( strtotime($newest_date) - strtotime($oldest_date) > 600 )
{
  echo '10 minutes has elapsed';
}
```

Where $newest_date is the most recent of the 2 dates and $oldest_date is the lowest. The 600 value is obtained by the following calculation: 10 minutes * 60 seconds = 600.